# Lower language tag influence on related questions

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I'm not sure if all language tags have this issue but at least in the topic I watch the [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) tag is actively harmful in helping find answers.

Examples:

[image]

[image]

In this next one you can see the [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) only added irrelevant results.

[image]

Is that a relatively low-hanging fruit type of adjustment to SO that would make SO more useful?

Comment: You have a steady hand, drawing such nice red free-hand "circles" ... *that look squarish ..*

Comment: @rene these need to be taken into forensics for further analysis to make sure they are actually hand-drawn. Use of a geometric tool would be a betrayal of our core principles, unthinkable. ಠ_ಠ

Comment: ... then again, perhaps we can forgive this specific instance because of the awesome lettering.

Comment: @rene Also the font, I can never achieve this accuracy with my mouse.

Comment: I think there was a similar Meta post related to "unrelated questions" before. I believe this also happened on other tags, like Java (or was it C?) with its unrelated "branching prediction" question.

Comment: Rather than draw them by hand I'll go train some deep learning to take my rectangles and make them appear to have been drawn by hand then PROFIT!